# why my one message disorder when use netty?

Tags: netty

I use netty 4.1.4.Final 
My message like this:
~1234567890...AAAA~
use '~' to split it
log:
2016-11-16 16:09:44.213 - 1，HashCode=-1614800617,S1=25,S2=-1,Length=26
2016-11-16 16:09:44.251 - 1，HashCode=-966536846,S1=25,S2=-1,Length=26
2016-11-16 16:09:44.267 - 1，HashCode=-989586955**,S1=9,S2=-1,Length=10
2016-11-16 16:09:44.358 - 1，HashCode=450805672,S1=57,S2=-1,Length=58
2016-11-16 16:09:44.383 - 1，HashCode=-1555716066,S1=57,S2=-1,Length=58
2016-11-16 16:09:45.403 - 3XXXX，HashCode=450805672,S1=0,S2=84,Length=85
2016-11-16 16:09:45.418 - 3XXXX，HashCode=-1555716066,S1=0,S2=84,Length=85
2016-11-16 16:09:45.476 - 3XXXX，HashCode=-1614800617,S1=0,S2=84,Length=85
2016-11-16 16:09:45.481 - 3XXXX，HashCode=-966536846,S1=0,S2=84,Length=85
2016-11-16 16:09:45.496 - 3XXXX，HashCode=-989586955,S1=0,S2=84,Length=85
Form the log，We can know that :
first Event, the variable msg equal to  "0...AAAA~"
the next Event ,then variable msg equal to  "~1234567890...AAAA~"
one message disorder, **but why**?

```html
public class MyMessageDecoder extends MessageToMessageDecoder<ByteBuf> {
private final static Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(BDCompatibleMessageDecoder.class);
 public void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf msg, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
    int readableBytes = msg.readableBytes();
    int startPosition = msg.indexOf(0, readableBytes, (byte)126);
    int endPosition = msg.indexOf(startPosition + 1, readableBytes, (byte)126);
    MyMessage message = null;
    if (endPosition > startPosition + 1) {
        Boolean xxx=ctx.channel().attr(NettyConstant.NETTY_CTX_XXX).get();
        if(xxx!=null&&xxx.equals(Boolean.TRUE)&&startPosition==0){
            ctx.channel().attr(NettyConstant.NETTY_CTX_XXX).set(Boolean.FALSE);
            LOGGER.info("3XXXX，HashCode="+ctx.channel().hashCode()+",startPosition =" + startPosition + ",endPosition=" + endPosition + ",Length=" + readableBytes);
        }

        if (startPosition > 0) {
            LOGGER.info("2XXXX，HashCode="+ctx.channel().hashCode()+",startPosition =" + startPosition + ",endPosition=" + endPosition + ",Length=" + readableBytes);
        }
        byte[] escapedData = new byte[endPosition - startPosition + 1];

        msg.readBytes(escapedData);
         // todoSomeThing 
    }
    if (startPosition > 0) {
        ctx.channel().attr(NettyConstant.NETTY_CTX_XXX).set(Boolean.TRUE);
        LOGGER.info("1，HashCode="+ctx.channel().hashCode()+",startPosition =" + startPosition + ",endPosition=" + endPosition + ",Length=" + readableBytes);
    }
    if (message != null) {
        out.add(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

MessageToMessageDecoder assumes that you are dealing with an already decoded message as input. You should be implementing a [ByteToMessageDecoder](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/ByteToMessageDecoder.html).

Take note about not modifying the reader index if you don't have enough bytes to create a message. Also consider creating a [DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder.html) and adding that earlier in the pipeline.